# Spring 3.1 not able to load Configuration Class:

Tags: spring, websphere, cglib

I am working on project that has Rest Service with Spring 3.1.0. Release.
I am using Config class to load beans. 
As suggested, using cglib 2.2 and asm-3.3 jars.

This fails in websphere 8.5 with following exception. But works in Apache Tomcat 7.0.

```
[12/19/12 12:47:26:439 EST] 00000062 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[dispatcher]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.hps.config.ApplicationConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:313)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:414)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1364)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2169)


Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY007 final method overridden; class=net/sf/cglib/core/DebuggingClassWriter, method=visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:762)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 109 more
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue.

Tried with different versions of cglib and asm jars, but no luck..

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve this issue..

Issue is with Websphere 8.5
It has own version of asm4.0 jars. And spring3.1 uses cglib2.2 jar that is only compatible with asm3.3. asm4.0 jar of websphere is the culprit.. 
workaround is to use cglib-nodep jar instead of cglib2.2 jar

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14880673

Comment: This ended up working for me, and I didn't have to mess with class loading.

Comment: Yes, it also works for me but, i didn't get the exact reason for this.

Comment: Not sure which part you didn't get. Error is because cglib2.2 jar is encountering asm4.0 jar of websphere and not the compatible asm3.3 jar that is part of your project ear/war file. So by using cglib-nodep.jar, you remove the dependency of cgblib on asm jars.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all the dependent JAR files are stored in `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your WAR file including Sam-3.3. If your using Maven then make sure you don't exclude this JAR or inadvertently set its scope as `provided`.

Now you you deploy the application in WebSphere make sure you set the application class loading before to application first (parent last). To do this in WebSphere you need to find the link `Manage Modules` and locate class loading link, don't really remember what it was in WebSphere however should be easy to find. This should resolve your issues.

Update: just noticed the link you provided already suggests using parent last. In WebSphere I find this is a must otherwise you will hit many of these issues and furthermore upgrades become much easier!

Comment: I could have done what u specified in your answer. I wish I can vote up your answer. Alas! I still don't have 15points to vote..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was a bug ([PM71336](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM71336)) in Websphere 8.5

The bug has been fixed in the Websphere V8.5 Fix Pack 2
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034672

Answer (score 0):

Use cglib-nodep jar instead of cglib2.2 jar. Also, don't forget to remove asm3.3 jar from your lib. Initially I wasn't removing asm3.3 jar which was still causing the problem.