# Weblogic deploy issue

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to deploy on Weblogic an EAR. During deploy i get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer
```

It seems to be a classpath error but i see that in my lib folder inside EAR is present the correct jar `cglib-nodep-3.0.jar`.

I am using: `Spring 3.1.0`

How can i fix it?

**Stacktrace:**

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:914) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:135) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at 
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:485) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427) at 
weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:637) at 
weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58) at 
weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at
weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at 
weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528) at
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:229) at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:171) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112) at
org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:109) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) at 
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) at
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at 
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58) 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at 
weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at 
weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636) at 
weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58) at 
weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140) at
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at 
weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to another question: [Spring 3.1 not able to load Configuration Class:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958414/spring-3-1-not-able-to-load-configuration-class) it may be a problem with Websphere's compatibility with cglib-nodep-3.0.

I'm using cglib-nodep-2.2 with WebSphere 8.5 and Spring 3.1 and it's working fine. Working with Websphere often means using older version of libraries...

Another ugly thing with Websphere it's that it often caches things it should not, especially after changing the library versions in the EAR. It's important to always stop server, make 'clean' (on server) and start again.

Comment: Thank Łukasz, it works!

I downgraded  cglib-nodep in my Maven configuration from 3.0 to 2.2 and has solved the problem.

But it is rather curious, the same Weblogic version (10.3) and java version (1.6) deploy correctly on Windows 7 but goes wrong in Ubuntu Linux with 3.0 jar.